# Feature counts don't match

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit to do a simple classification task. I have a test and train data set, their shapes are as follows: train = (1000, 69917) and test = (1073, 49429). When I do something like:

```
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 49429 features per sample; expecting 69917
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `X_train` is used to train the model, during the prediction stage the model will expect `X_test` to have the exact same feature dimension (i.e. number of columns).

You mentioned that `X_train` and `X_test` are produced using a CountVectorizer. A likely cause of this problem is that you called `fit` (or `fit_transform`) twice, producing two different transformations. To prevent that from happening, ensure that there is only one call to`fit`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vec.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
X_test = vec.transform(X_test_raw) # Not fit_transform!
```

This way, the test data will be transformed using the exact same set of vocabulary learnt from the training data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your testing and training sets so that they each have a different number of values, but the same number of features.

Answer (score -1):

X_train and y_train must have the same number of rows. I.e. For each training example the classifier needs a target to learn.

You will also run into issues when you 'predict' as train and test set should have the same number of columns.

Suggest you read a good introductory text before you keep going. This is good:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Edit: misread q. Ignore mismatching rows in y_train. You just need to ensure train and test have same columns.

Comment: How do I ensure both have the same number of columns? I've used a count vectorizer on them at different places.

Comment: Before any transformation (like vectorization) you must concat your train and test set. After transformation you can split again.